# Mismatching types when trying to assign to optional property

Tags: swift, null, option-type, ternary-operator

I have a CoreData object with a `foo` property

```
var foo: NSNumber?
```

Now I want to assign a value to it, but that value is a optional: `Int64?`

I tried the following:

```
var bar:Int64?
foo = bar != nil ? NSNumber(value:bar!) : nil
```

but that results in

```
Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'NSNumber' and '_'`
```

Is there a easy way to make this work? I tried `nil as NSNumber?` but that did not do the trick.

Comment: The simplest solution is to declare the CoreData attribute as Swift type `var foo: Int64?` That avoids the bridge dance. Although the default numeric Core Data type is `NSNumber` Swift native types work very well.

Comment: In  my Xcode 8 and 9 the compiler complains at `NSNumber(value:bar)` because `bar` is not unwrapped ...

Comment: Yes, sorry, the actual code has indeed a unwrapped `bar`

Comment: @vadian yes, that would be much easier. But it doesn't seem possible to do that when generating the CoreData classes? Or am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: I'm always generating the class manually via the menu item and change the types I need. I'm changing also the default optional types to non-optionals according to my model.

Comment: @vadian ah ok. I frequently need to update my model with new fields, so I am relying on the generation via the menu. It is too much work to change everything every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because in the expression `foo = bar != nil ? NSNumber(value:bar) : nil`, the `bar` you're trying to pass to `NSNumber(value:)` is still optional. You could use the force unwrap (`!`) operator to unwrap it, but it's not as elegant as the proper solution:

This is a perfect use case for `Optional.map`:

```
foo = bar.map{ NSNumber(value: $0) }
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that it's indeed a unwrapped `bar`. This solution seems nice. Still don't like it that I can't just use a ternary operator. Swift should understand that a `nil` is a optional `NSNumber`

Comment: @Peterdk It does, but that's not the issue. `bar` needs to be unwrapped before being passed off to NSNumber. `foo = bar != nil ? NSNumber(value: bar!) : nil` [compiles fine.](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ea30951b6536583365e593)

Comment: it's weird. I tried it and it compiles indeed. I rechecked the code and added parentheses to the original code that failed to compile, and now it works. I also checked that it worked on Swift 3. I guess I made a weird mistake somewhere, cause it works as it should now. :| Maybe I did indeed forget to unwrap originally.